# Prusa i3 - First layer does not stick and looks jagged

Tags: prusa-i3, ultimaker-cura

My first layer is suddenly not sticking for every new print I'm trying. When it lays down the first layer it has this weird jaggedness to it, doesn't firmly stick to the plate, and gets dragged by the nozzle. I've printed previously successful prints without an issue, but any new print I export from Cura is having this issue. I'm using the same profile that I do for the previously successful ones.

My relevant print settings are:

- Material: PLA
- Layer height: .2mm
- Hotend: 205c
- Plate: 60c
- Fan cooling: 50%
- Speed: 60mm/s

[image: Problem print]

Comment: It could also be that the heatbed temperature is too low - do you confirm that actual printing temperature matches the desired value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nozzle is too far from the build plate. You should make some changes to bring the nozzle closer to the build plate for the first layer. There are a number of possibilities for doing this:

1. Adjust the Z-axis endstop
2. Loosen the bed leveling screws
3. Add an offset in G-code

This will squish the plastic down more, enabling it to stick to the build plate.

With solution (3), you have to be careful that you don't crash into the endstop. This solution works best if your printer homes towards max (and not min) or if you have non-mechanical (hall or optical) endstops.

Comment: Answer is perfect except the offset part. Usually the z-endstop is a screw touching the switch and if you offset it to go lower than that, it might cause collision of the screw on the switch causing damage to the endstop.

Comment: That is a good point. I didn't think about this because my printer homes towards max.