# Filament moving around and not sticking to bed

Tags: troubleshooting, adhesion, anet-a6

I have only just set up my Anet A6 today. I am trying to print a calibration box, but the print is moving around the bed while trying to print. Any ideas how to fix this? The documentation is very vague.

Basically I am very new to 3D printing. I purchased an Anet A6 and have set it up stock. I am trying to just print the box directly from the demo models on the SD card. I'm using the standard filament that comes with the printer. I'm not sure what type it is.

All settings are default.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! More than likely you don't have the bed leveled correctly, or you don't have the bed hot enough. You really don't give us any information as to what exactly you're doing. Please edit your question and include what type of filament you're using (PLA, ABS, etc), the heat settings (bed/extruder), and what slicer you've used to make your monstrosity. This will help us be able to help you.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Hawkins bed adhesion is a pretty common type of question. That said I would need photos etc to see exactly what is happening. That said this might be related https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4774/prusa-i3-first-layer-does-not-stick-and-looks-jagged

Answer (score 3):

If the printed material moves with the nozzle, you might have several problems at hand, e.g.:

- adhesion,
- nozzle to bed distance and
- overall level.

Nozzle to bed distance needs to be the thickness of a plain A4 or Letter paper. This needs to be at the same distance (when pulling the sheet of paper you need to feel a little drag) at the complete area of the bed. This is sometimes difficult as not all beds are perfectly flat from itself. Finally, you need to pull some tricks out of your sleeve to get the filament to adhere to the bed. Many example can be found, popular ones are using blue tape, glass bed, glue stick, PVA based spray (e.g. strong hairspray or dedicated spray cans like 3DLAC or Dimafix, etc.), or a combination of these. You just need to experiment some more what works best for you, but it is good to start with a correctly levelled bed with the proper nozzle gap. Sometimes, increasing the bed and filament temperature with 5 °C for the first layer also helps.

Comment: When i try to get it this low, it seems to scrape the bottom of the bed. Im sure my bed isnt level, as i can get it spot on on both sides, but then when i move the head across there is a gap in the middle

Comment: [Video of the attempted print of sample box](https://sendvid.com/dpibrbpx)

Comment: @AndrewHawkins Then it would be a great time to invest in automatic bed levelling. But from the video can be seen that you do not have enough adhesion also.

Comment: Thanks, do you think thats the key issue then , the adhesion? if i try hairspray as reccomended by @dcoll, do i just spray it on the bed and rub it around?

Comment: @AndrewHawkins Yes I recommended you to use hairspray if you don't have a specific product for bed adhesion. Glue-stick will also work, that is basically PVA, wood glue should also work. Please experiment, but if the bed has a too big of a dent it will not work. However, in your video you don't start in the middle with printing which let me believe that the bed adhesion in not optimal. You can also increase the bed temperature by 5 °C. Please [edit] your question and insert print temperature and bed temperature.

Answer (score 2):

Also check your speed settings. 
1st layer should always be printed 50% of the normal speed, if not less. (my choice is 20mm/s)

If your overall printing speed is really fast, collision with already printed lines may be the issue. You can try either slow down movement/print or avoid/retract over peripherals.

Any hairspray containing **neodecanoate copolymer** is a great adhesion, and very cheap :)

Answer (score -1):

Chances are, you're not levelled close enough. try levelling your bed when it's heated around 60C (or as high as you can get if your machine's FW won't let it go that high) with a piece of standard printer paper. you should get a bit of resistance, and play around with the paper for a bit, find a happy medium. Try spreading glue stick on your bed, or spray it with hairspray. If you have BuildTak or some form of PEI, wipe it with some 99% rubbing alcohol. Lastly, find a fairly simple model on thingiverse.com or myminifactory.com, and slice it using either Raft or Skirt as build plate adhesion. I prefer a skirt because you can actively be checking how your bed levelling is, and adjust it. And make sure your first layer flow or extrusion multiplier is slightly higher is about 110-120%. This can get you good sticking almost every time.

Comment: Please troubleshoot based on the information given, which states "anet A6, as it comes shipped". Look up the specs on Gearbest if you need - half the information you give here is just not applicable to this machine.